# How to write the expression to disable an input text after entered a particular string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Now I have something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cell.location">
```

What I want is while you put 'ABC' in this field, this field will become disabled status, I know I can put a boolean param to control it via its controller.

However what I expect is something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="{{cell.location = 'ABC'}}" ng-model="cell.location">
```

Which is clearer and simpler, unfortunately this approach doesn't work as expected, it will assign 'ABC' to this field rather than disable it. is that possible to implement in this kind of way?

Thanks.

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator. Use `==` or `===`. Also, `ng-disabled` uses an expression, meaning you don't wrap the value in `{{ }}`, eg `ng-disabled="cell.location == 'ABC'"`

Comment: @Phil yes, this is a clear understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this with `==`:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="cell.location == 'ABC'" ng-model="cell.location" />
```

Instead of:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="{{cell.location = 'ABC'}}" ng-model="cell.location">
```

[Angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Answer (score 1):

Use this without {{}}:

`<input type="text" ng-disabled="cell.location == 'ABC'" ng-model="cell.location" />`

Instead of:

`<input type="text" ng-disabled="{{cell.location = 'ABC'}}" ng-model="cell.location">`